Node error while running npx create next app
I am trying to create a next project using npx but i am getting an error
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
I was trying to create next project using npx create next app

Try reinstalling latest version of node and just to make sure run npm install -g npm then run npx create-next-app@latest

@JayendraAwasthi This resolved it perfectly . Appreciated

Try to clear the npm Cache.
To clear the npm cache, run npm cache clean --force
or
Reinstall npm:

Open a command prompt or terminal as an administrator.
to uninstall npm globally, run npm uninstall -g npm
then to reinstall npm, run npm install -g npm


I was facing the same problem.
You need to completely delete Node.JS from your system. Please refer this article(Click here)
Reinstall Node.JS, preferably lts version.
The issue must be resolved, if it still continues, go into AppData folder(it is present as hidden folders in some systems). Go into roaming folder and create a folder named 'npm' This should resolve your issue.
Restart your PC and create-react-app, create-next-app should work properly.
